# React router dom v6 matchPatch is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react router dom v6, and I would like to match a path with current url.

this is the path I would like to check.
`:workspaceMasterStoreDataId?/account/:masterDataAccountId/list`

this is what `useMatches` return so the current location :

```
params:{workspaceMasterStoreDataId: '1031', masterDataAccountId: '12'}
pathname:"/1031/account/12/list"
```

I would like to check if my path match or not.

I tried many ways

```
  const test = matchPath(":workspaceMasterStoreDataId?/account/:masterDataAccountId/list", pathname);
  const tests = matchPath(
    `:workspaceMasterStoreDataId/account/:masterDataAccountId/list`,
    pathname
  );
  const test3s = matchPath(
    `/:workspaceMasterStoreDataId?/account/:masterDataAccountId/list`,
    pathname
  );
  const test33s = matchPath(
    `/:workspaceMasterStoreDataId/account/:masterDataAccountId/list`,
    pathname
  );
  const test1s = matchPath(
    `:workspaceMasterStoreDataId/account/:masterDataAccountId/list`,
    pathname
  );
  const testss = matchPath(
    {path: `:workspaceMasterStoreDataId?/account/:masterDataAccountId/list`},
    pathname
  );
```

but it never matches, am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `"?"` in the path pattern. Try `"/:workspaceMasterStoreDataId/account/:masterDataAccountId/list"` as the path pattern.

```js
const pattern = "/:workspaceMasterStoreDataId/account/:masterDataAccountId/list";
const pathname = "/1031/account/12/list";

const match = matchPath(pattern, pathname);
```

`match` Result:

```
{
  params: {
    workspaceMasterStoreDataId: '1031',
    masterDataAccountId: '12'
  },
  pathname: "/1031/account/12/list",
  pathnameBase: "/1031/account/12/list",
  pattern: {
    path: '/:workspaceMasterStoreDataId/account/:masterDataAccountId/list', 
    caseSensitive: false,
    end: true
  }
}
```

Seems odd that optional route path parameters are acceptable for the `Route` component's `path` prop, but doesn't work here. I see it listed as a [feature request](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9793) in the RRD github repo and in [open discussion](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9862) ATM.

Comment: yeah, I think it"s a bug, it doesnt work with optional parameter, I need to force the `workspaceMasterStoreDataId` but then it doesnt match if there is no `workspaceMasterStoreDataId` so I need 2 matches... I guess I ll raise a bug ticket T.T THank you

Comment: @Bobby Yeah, just found a filed issue in the repo. FWIW they only just reintroduced optional params not too long ago in v6.5.0. Obviously some kinks to work out still.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are not using the API right. It's like this:

```
const match = matchPath(":workspaceMasterStoreDataId?/account/:masterDataAccountId/list", {
  path: pathname,
});
```

Comment: this is v5 not v6

Comment: Apologies. In the title you mention v6. Make sure `react-router` and `React router dom` are the same major version as they are not cross compatible I beleive.